# Symfony 2 Validate route params with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, parameters, fosrestbundle

I have a delete route like so, using FOSRestBundle

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @Rest\View
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    ...
}
```

I want to make sure that the id parameter is numeric.
I tried :

```
@Route("/delete/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
```

And

```
@QueryParam(name="id", requirements="\d+", description="User id")
```

And

```
@RequestParam(name="id", requirements="\d+", description="User id")
```

But none of these solutions work. Either the route is not found, or the constraint is not respected.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but does not return a JSON encoded 404 response when trying to access a route like `api/users/xx.json`

```
@Rest\Delete("/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
```